# How to read no quoted csv file using CsvHelper library?

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core, csvhelper

I need to read csv file content using CsvHelper library. Here's my method responsible for reading a file:

```
        public virtual async Task<ICollection<Shipment>> GetMaterialReleaseReceiptsAsync(string filePath)
        {
            var validShipmentData = new List<Shipment>();

            try
            {
                using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                using var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;

                var shipment = await csvReader
                    .GetRecordsAsync<ShipmentData>()
                    .Select(s => new Shipment
                        {
                            Issue = s.Issue,
                            MaterialReleaseReceipt = s.MaterialReleaseReceipt,
                            FileLocation = filePath
                        })
                    .ToListAsync();

                validShipmentData = SortOutShipmentData(shipment, filePath)
                    .ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var errorMessage = e.InnerException != null
                    ? $"{e.Message} {e.InnerException.Message}"
                    : e.Message;

                await EventBus
                    .PublishAsync(new FileProcessExceptionEvent
                    {
                        Description = errorMessage,
                        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                        FileLocation = filePath
                    });
            }

            return validShipmentData;
        }
```

Example row of my csv file looks like this:

...
"06/08/2020";"ABCD";"1234"
...

The problem is, that some files imported to my api, contain no quotes. Exemplary row shown below:

...
06/08/2020;ABCD;1234
...

When such a file comes to my application, an exception is being thrown, while trying to get records from file. Quoted files are processed properly. Exception contains the following message:

"No members are mapped for type '...'"

Of course columns specified in header are compliant with ShipmentData definition. The only problem i've noticed are missing quotes around cells. I would like to rewrite my method to be able to get records from both types of csv. How to achieve that using CsvHelper library?? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I thought that quotes were only needed when the text contains the separator. I have used CsvHelper with files without quotes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @insane_developer you may be right, but i have no influence on the quotes. These files are imported my api by users, and i just need to process them :)

Comment: @insane_developer is right.  It should work without the quotes as long as there isn't a separator or line break in one of the fields.  Can you provide sample data where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use Read() and loop through the rows, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/909), [example in this comment](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/909#issuecomment-368136256).